# Angular Bootstrap UIB-Datepicker-Popup Search Filtering and Clearing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker, angularjs-filter

I've scoured the web and SO for answers to two UI Bootstrap questions but haven't had any luck so far. I have an Angular 1.5.8 app using the UI Bootstrap `uib-datepicker-popup` directive for **start_date** and **end_date** inputs on a table. The inputs are used to filter the table by each date. Right now when I select a date to filter using the `uib-datepicker-popup` input or calendar, the table does not filter the dates. I believe it has to do with the difference in data types between my table data and the `Date()` object the datepicker creates, but so far I cannot come up with a fix for it. I am also experiencing an issue with clearing the date filters since the default `clear()` function sets the model to `null` instead of `undefined`.

[Here is a Plunker demonstrating the issue.](http://plnkr.co/edit/umuysNsDCGdbSQXNYhz1?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<table id="profiles" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="col-lg-3">Name
    <input ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search Name" type="text" class="form-control">
  </th>
  <th class="col-lg-3">ID
    <input ng-model="search.id" placeholder="Search ID" type="text" class="form-control">
  </th>
  <th class="col-lg-3">Start Date
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Search Start Date"
             uib-datepicker-popup 
             ng-model="search.start_date" 
             is-open="startDateOpen" 
             close-text="Close"
             ng-change="checkDate('start_date)"
      />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="startDateOpen = !startDateOpen">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </th>
  <th class="col-lg-3">End Date
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Search End Date"
             uib-datepicker-popup 
             ng-model="search.end_date" 
             is-open="endDateOpen" 
             close-text="Close"
             ng-change="checkDate('end_date')"
      />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="endDateOpen = !endDateOpen">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: search">
        <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
        <td>{{profile.id}}</td>
        <td>{{profile.start_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td>{{profile.end_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**example.js**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', 
function ($scope) {

$scope.profiles = [
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    id: 1,
    start_date: '2018-01-02',
    end_date : '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarah',
    id: 2,
    start_date: '2019-01-01',
    end_date : '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeff',
    id: 3,
    start_date: '2018-11-01',
    end_date : '2019-01-01'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jenn',
    id: 4,
    start_date: '2018-11-01',
    end_date : '2019-01-01'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    id: 5,
    start_date: '2017-11-01',
    end_date : '2018-01-01'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ann',
    id: 6,
    start_date: '2017-11-01',
    end_date : '2018-01-01'
  }
];

$scope.search = {};

// $scope.search.start_date = '2018-01-02';

// Used to log the data and data type
$scope.types = {
  search_start_date: typeof($scope.search.start_date),
  profile_0_start_date: typeof($scope.profiles[0].start_date)
}

// convertDates($scope.profiles);

function convertDates(profiles) {
    angular.forEach(profiles, function(profile) {
        profile.start_date = new Date(profile.start_date);
        profile.start_date.setHours(0,0,0);
        profile.end_date = new Date(profile.end_date);
        profile.end_date.setHours(0,0,0);
    });
}

$scope.checkDate = function(type) {
  $scope.search[type] = $scope.search[type] ? $scope.search[type] : 
undefined;
}

});
```

As you'll see in the Plunker, I've got some dummy data with a Name, ID, Start Date, and End Date. The Name and ID columns are there to show that the filtering is working as intended. The dummy data, `$scope.profiles`, mimics the way that **start_date** and **end_date** are returned from my database. Both are stored as `date` types in MySQL and returned as a 'yyyy-MM-dd' string (no times attached). I can re-format these date strings on the front end in any way that's necessary to get the filtering working. For instance, in my Plunker example I've added this function:

```
function convertDates(profiles) {
    angular.forEach(profiles, function(profile) {
        profile.start_date = new Date(profile.start_date);
        profile.start_date.setHours(0,0,0);
        profile.end_date = new Date(profile.end_date);
        profile.end_date.setHours(0,0,0);
    });
}
```

to convert the dates to JS Date() objects if needed, though it's currently commented out since I don't think this is the right approach. Also, if I do convert the **start_date** and **end_date** to Date() objects, the filtering still doesn't work as I'm trying to compare two objects instead of numbers or strings.

Now what I notice is that if I define one of the search dates in the controller, for instance `$scope.search.start_date` (which is currently commented out), the **start_date** will populate in the input and the table will filter correctly. It's data type is also string, not object. Therefore I'm curious as to why typing in the date manually or selecting it from the `uib-datepicker-popup` doesn't have the same effect? I'm guessing that pre-defining doesn't trigger the directive and convert it a Date() object. I found this one thread where a user is requesting that date string be an optional data type for the ng-model instead of Date() object: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1239. There is a directive recommended there that should allow you to set ng-model as a date string instead of Date() objects, but I've had no success when trying to use it.

My second issue is with clearing the inputs. The **Clear** button will effectively set each date model to `null`, however, the filter will sort on `null` and not actually clear as intended. I have this dummy function in the example:

```
$scope.checkDate = function(type) {
    $scope.search[type] = $scope.search[type] ? $scope.search[type] : 
    undefined;
}
```

Which is called on `ng-change` like so:

```
<input type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search Start Date"
        uib-datepicker-popup 
        ng-model="search.start_date" 
        is-open="startDateOpen" 
        close-text="Close"
        ng-change="checkDate('start_date)"
 />
```

This hack actually works locally to clear the input and filtering, however, it doesn't work in the Plunker and once again I highly doubt it's a good approach. Any help on this would be appreciated, I'm using a CDN to serve UI Bootstrap right now but I have no issue downloading it and modifying the directive to set ng-model as a date string if needed. I think that being able to just use date strings would be the easiest approach, but I'm  interested to see if there is a way to achieve this without having to alter the `uib-datepicker-popup` directive. I've used this same datepicker popup in a past project with dates that were strings and the filter worked as intended, however, I cannot recreate that behavior in my Plunker or my new project. Please let me know if any more information is needed to answer my questions. Thank you in advance for your help!